# Drupal and Facebook - Fboauth timeout

Tags: social-network

I have a website running on a VPS with centos 6.6 and recently my login with facebook system stopped working with no apparent reason... Every time I try to login with facebook I receive the following error:

> The Facebook login could not be completed due to an error. Please
>   create an account or contact us directly. Details about this error
>   have already been recorded to the error log.

So I checked the error log and:

Facebook OAuth could not acquire an access token from Facebook. We queried the following URL:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token?client_id=....&client_secret=....&redirect_uri=http%3A//portugalcinegetico.pt/fboauth/connect&code=AQAspHBdtFnb9YYjcKtvp-iqozEXiEr8xe5OCD_S4ONyqv2peWwl3wUDN6dzEMq88s2FlPc-y8_7RuCk_R52e4lTuoRjn-rbQ25LqVTeKPFOXqDH36PiD3ecJeOFAgFwK5ocfJHXH7yINER6cRbuOTCf9CVZyyUp0TkDLMOu3YOfFo6GxZh4lWiRp1UB4N9nr18lwfiTYfoNTQKR4eSv7VeH7Ak0dgHWC27dBcs-H8cVUbTRMG92ehvgbdCUR5wbakbYK3Ji5yxIh3hSQ_duZIoEFTcGxBB5fUSzRlMLretSTs-ox7c6314zID-bYRRvBLg
>
> . Facebook's servers returned an error Connection timed out:
>
> (no data returned)

Can anyone help me with this. I already checked all configurations in my facebook app and in drupal fboauth...

Thanks in advance!